# Excel: Custom format of date that excel cannot notice

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, date

My problem looks like this:

`Dec 8, 2022, 8:35:04 AM`

I need to let excel see this format as. I tried date to columns option, it didn't work. I did it in like 10 steps. Can it be done any simpler by defining this format to excel ? I need to see date format for this field so I can use it in calculating difference. I was trying to transform it in something like

```
=TEXT(D2;"[$-en-US] mmm d, rrrr, g:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

to let excel save it as number or whatever. I need to calculate difference between date that I gave to you and `11.11.2022 08:24:32` (this is successfully detected as date), but in excel that has few thousand entries

Comment: Please add more details, your post as it's now is hard to understand.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose. The gray word `Edit` below the question is a link for editing.

Comment: Did you try the Custom Format? How did you set the Custom Format? What is the source  number?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to convert this into a date:
Dec 8, 2022, 8:35:04 AM

If that's the case and supposing the above is in cell A1, then this will work if you have the TEXTBEFORE function:

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXTBEFORE(A1,", ",2))
```

If you don't have the TEXTBEFORE function, try this:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(", ",A1,9)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Not totally what i meant but thanks to this I can now use this and add time to this and have datetime which I can use in my calculations. Youre the boss!

Comment: =DATEVALUE(LEFT(D2;FIND(", ";D2;9)-1))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(D2;(FIND(", ";D2;9)-1)))